# Docker Using a custom MySQL configuration file Always fail

Tags: mysql, docker

[Follow the documentation here,Always fail](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql?tab=description)

> Using a custom MySQL configuration file
>   The default configuration for MySQL can be found in /etc/mysql/my.cnf, which may !includedir additional directories such as /etc/mysql/conf.d or /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d. Please inspect the relevant files and directories within the mysql image itself for more details.
>
> If /my/custom/config-file.cnf is the path and name of your custom configuration file, you can start your mysql container like this (note that only the directory path of the custom config file is used in this command):
>
> $ docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag
>   This will start a new container some-mysql where the MySQL instance uses the combined startup settings from /etc/mysql/my.cnf and /etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf, with settings from the latter taking precedence.
>
> Configuration without a cnf file
>   Many configuration options can be passed as flags to mysqld. This will give you the flexibility to customize the container without needing a cnf file. For example, if you want to change the default encoding and collation for all tables to use UTF-8 (utf8mb4) just run the following:
>
> $ docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
>   If you would like to see a complete list of available options, just run:

#### My version Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d

The commands I run

> docker run --name mysql2 -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:8.0.16

My custom configuration file

```xml
[mysqld]
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Comment: Can you show the container logs?

Comment: I found the reason, because mysql.cnf has 777 permissions

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. Because I set the `mysql.cnf` permissions to 777.